# Traffic logging similar to Statcounter

Tags: linux, web-apps, monitoring, logs

Is there an open source server software that enables web-analytics like that of statcounter.com where I can host my own logs, and insert Javascript into the html of say a Tumblr blog to enable traffic monitoring?

I would like it to:

- Run on Linux (Ubuntu)
- Operate on a home media server with performance PC parts.
- Enable me to see IP addresses with time stamps

Comment: I've used awstats a long time ago for such a task. But its been too long to still justify a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the consideration, but I found a great alternative to those hosted analytic services with an open source analytics platform. It also has a JavaScript Tracking Tag just like statcounter.

### [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

**How it meets the requirements:**

- **Run on Linux:** Piwik has a Debian repository
- **Operate on a home media server with performance PC parts:** It will work well for consumer-level use on a performance PC configured to be a server. minimum 4GB RAM
- **Enable me to see IP addresses with time stamps:** It has a visitor log that displays calendar date and IP addresses, additionally you can view raw data in the SQL tables.

[image: Piwik] [image: Piwik]
<sup>*Piwik* screenshots (source: [T3N](http://t3n.de/news/open-web-analytics-piwik-echte-alternativen-google-297614/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

*Piwik* …

- is free & open source
- offers user privacy protection (you have 100% data ownership)
- offers user-centric insights
- is customisable and extensible

Comment: @Izzy Well, thanks for this lesson in Q&A formatting.

Comment: You're welcome again! Check this one :) // *Piwik* sounds really interesting, maybe I'll take a closer look at it myself one day. Thanks for your updates!

Comment: PS: While surely an improvement over GoogleAnalytics (have someone else track your users), one has to keep in mind that Piwik as well tracks your users via Cookies. True, you can anonymize the IP addresses; but I don't like to be tracked (and don't want my users to be tracked), so I guess *I* stay away from it on my websites. But that's my personal feeling, YMMV :)

Comment: Wow, this is a vast improvement to my original post. Thank you for the template, I'll favorite it for future reference. Have a great day!